# How can I 'refresh' a component in Angular without reloading a page?

Tags: angular5

The menu bar of my application should have text inputs and sign in button if user is not logged in and it should have a sign out button when the user is logged in. These two groups are mutually exclusive.

I have written the code as follows:

```
<div *ngIf=”userNotLoggedIn”>
  <li>some li</li>
</div>
<div *ngIf=”!userNotLoggedIn”>
  <li>some other li</li>
</div>
```

The `userNotLoggedIn` is initially set to `true` and gets updated to `false` once login is successful. My issue is that the change in value of `userNotLoggedIn` doesnt update my component i.e. I still see the login/password text and not sign out link.

I also tried this variant but that doesn't work either

```
<div >
  <li [hidden]=”userNotLoggedIn”>some li</li>
</div>
<div>
  <li [hidden]=”!userNotLoggedIn”>some other li</li>
</div>
```

The `userNotloggedIn:boolean` is defined as boolean and I set its initial value to `true` in `ngOnInit`

```
 ngOnInit(){

    this.userNotloggedIn = true;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are setting your `bool` for `*ngIf` and that you are using negation correctly. It should work perfectly fine with the first example you provided.

Comment: Thanks. your assumed correctly that I might not be setting the `boolean` correctly. I had set it wrongly, in the wrong code leg.